# Cropping pictures with jcrop

Tags: jquery, image, jcrop

I want to do the exact same thing as this page: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/crop.php
However, I didn't find the code anywhere! Any idea how I can do it? Is there an other method than Jcrop?

Thanks!

Comment: How about http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html ?

Comment: there are lots of examples I found by just Googling it. http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-crop-image-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not a good question for StackOverflow, check the page you provide and you will see:

- the manual: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html
- the server side guide:
  http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html

In the first link in the section [`Further Reading`](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Further_Reading) you can find more useful documentation.